# How to check the value of an attribute inside the get method TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Can anyone help me with this problem in TypeScript 2.3.

Problem: My backend sends me a property in Json with value 00 or 01, I need to convert to Regular or Extra.

I tried to check the values ​​of the attribute descViagem and return a string in method get. but the is return undefined

```
  export class InfoViagem {
  descViagem: string;

  public get $descViagem(): string {
      switch (this.descViagem) {
        case "00":
          return "REGULAR";

        case "01":
          return "EXTRA";

        default:
          return "Tipo inválido";
      }
    }
}

//Using in:
    <div class="col-md-2 mb-4">
      <label>Tipo viagem</label>
       <input type="text" [value]="viagem?.descViagem  (ngModel)="viagem.descViagem" class="form-control" disabled>
    </div>
```

Comment: The posted code seems correct. How do you use the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're using is an object created by parsing JSON. It's a plain old JS object. **Not** an instance of `InfoViagem`.

You can only have an instance of `InfoViagem` if you create one using its constructor: `new InfoViagem()`.

So obviously, you get undefined since there is no `$descViagem` in the JSON, and thus no `$descViagem` property in the POJO created by parsing the JSON.